# Почему получаю в get запросе ?id=[object%20Object]?

Tags: angular, angular10

Вот такая ошибка

```
GET http://localhost:60397/printingedition/getprintingedition?id=[object%20Object]
```

Получаю printingEdition по id из сервера, метод в сервисе

```
getPrintingEdition(id: number): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get<PrintingEdition>(`${environment.apiUrl}printingedition/getprintingedition?id=` + id);
}
```

В компоненте с параметра получаю id

```
id: string;
В ngOnInit:
this.id = this.activateRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
```

Когда вывожу в консоль id, то выводит то что нужно. Ответ 2

```
console.log(this.id);
```

Дальше диспатчу action

```
this.store$.dispatch(new GetPrintingEdition(Number(this.id)));
```

Мой редюсер

```
export const getPrintingEditionReducer = (
    state = initialGetPrintingEditionState,
    action: GetPrintingEditionAction
): GetPrintingEditionState => {
    switch (action.type){
        
        case EGetPrintingEdition.GetPrintingEditionSuccess: {
            return {
                ...state,
                idPrintingEdition: action.payload,
                printingEdition: action.payload,
            };
        }
        default: {
            return {
                ...state
            };
        }
    }
};
```

Сам action

```
export class GetPrintingEdition implements Action{
    public readonly type =  EGetPrintingEdition.GetPrintingEdition;
    constructor(public payload: number){}
}

export class GetPrintingEditionSuccess implements Action{
    public readonly type =  EGetPrintingEdition.GetPrintingEditionSuccess;
    constructor(public payload: any){}
}
```

Стейт

```
export interface GetPrintingEditionState{
    idPrintingEdition: number;
    printingEdition: PrintingEdition;

}

export const initialGetPrintingEditionState: GetPrintingEditionState = {
    idPrintingEdition: null,
    printingEdition: null,

}
```

Effect отрабатывает и мне выводит в консоль иyформацию которую я запрашиваю по id

```
 @Effect()
    GetPrintingEdition = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType<printingEditionAction.GetPrintingEdition>(printingEditionAction.EGetPrintingEdition.GetPrintingEdition),
        mergeMap((action: printingEditionAction.GetPrintingEdition) => 
            this.adminService.getPrintingEdition(action.payload).pipe(
                map((model) => {
                    console.log(model);
                    return new printingEditionAction.GetPrintingEditionSuccess(model);
                })
            ))
    )
```

AppState

```
export interface AppState{

    account?: AccountState;
    admin?: AdminState;
    author?: AuthorState;
    user?: UserState;
    errorMessage?: BaseErrorState;
    getPrintingEdition?: GetPrintingEditionState;
}

export const appReducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
}

export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<AppState>[] = !environment.production ? [] : [];
```

AppModule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(appReducers, { metaReducers }),
    StoreModule.forFeature(appReducer.appReducer, appReducer.appReducers),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 25, logOnly: environment.production }),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([GetPrintingEditionEffect]),
    StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot(),
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config:{
        tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
        allowedDomains: [environment.apiUrl],
      }
    }),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule
 
  ],
  providers:
  [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    AuthGuardService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

GetPrintingEdition selector

```
import { createSelector, createFeatureSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import { PrintingEdition } from 'src/app/pages/printing-edition/models/printing-edition.interface';
import { appReducer } from '../reducers/app-reducer.reducer';
import { AppState } from '../state/app-state.state';

const selectPrintingEdition = createFeatureSelector<AppState>(appReducer);


export const getPrintingEdition = createSelector(
    selectPrintingEdition,
    (state: AppState) => state.getPrintingEdition.printingEdition
);
```

Comment: у Вас id - это Object. А вот почему так получилось - это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: @KoVadim так почему мне так возвращает?

Comment: @KoVadim посмотрите сейчас я передаю число не объект и все равно та же ошибка

Comment: Number - это объект. я плохо знаю javascript, но может там написать id.toString (в функции getPrintingEdition)

Comment: @KoVadim понял) У вас нет вариантов как решить эту проблему?

Comment: @ KoVadim написал id.toString() ничего не изменилось

Comment: Стейт у вас меняется? Редьюсер не обрабатывает тип `EGetPrintingEdition.GetPrintingEdition`

Comment: @Adrug стейт меняется, только что я сделал что б редьюсер обрабатывал тип EGetPrintingEdition.GetPrintingEdition , но все как и раньше

Comment: @Adrug idPrintingEdition(pin):null => '2' стейт меняет

Comment: @Adrug сервер отрабатывает отлично, это уже на клиенте какие то проблемы, из сервера все приходит отлично, не могу понять что не так

Comment: Какой-то код, который вы тут не указали, пишет  в стейт объект, а не строку.

Comment: @Adrug возможно app state

Comment: @Adrug посмотрите выше пожалуйста, добавил appstate, selector, app.module

Comment: дОБАВЬ лог перед отправкой `getPrintingEdition(id: number): Observable<any>{ console.log(id);
    return this.http.get<PrintingEdition>(\`${environment.apiUrl}printingedition/getprintingedition?id=\` + id);
}` и посмотри что действительно ты передаешь

Comment: @ Grundy♦ добавлял сначала выводит id действительно которое нужно, а потом весь обьект по этом id